# Pass object to controller and when I check the object in the controller and its only getting the date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am putting a string into localStorage

```
StorageBin.Keys = function (key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

and when I check it, the values are in there.

So I go to send it over to my controller

```
function TossIt(a, b) {

    var sendFruitList = JSON.parse(StorageBin.Get("FruitSold"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/PedrosFruitStandHome/GetFruitTotals?toDate=" + a + "&fromDate=" + b,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { fruitlist: sendFruitList },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            TallyGrid(data);
        },
        complete: function (e) {
        }
    })
}
```

and here is the controller that I am sending it to

```
public JsonResult GetFruitTotals(List<Models.FruitStandStuff> fruitlist, string toDate, string fromDate)
    {
        pfs = new PFS();
        var result = pfs.TotalsByDateRange(fruitlist, toDate, fromDate);

        return result; 
    }
```

when I check fruitlist, all it contains is the date that is in the string that I call from localStorage.

here is the class that I am using for a list

```
public class FruitStandStuff
    {
        public string FruitName { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
    }
```

I have no idea why its not getting all the values and here is the list of values

> [{"FruitName":"Oranges","Qty":"2","Price":"30","DateSold":"2017-03-12"},{"FruitName":"Apples","Qty":"2","Price":"30","DateSold":"2017-03-12"}]

and here is a screenshot of what my objects look like when its parsed

[image: Parsed data]

I have no idea why, in the controller, I am only getting the DateSold and not the other values

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ fruitlist: sendFruitList }),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, tried that earlier and get this error
GetFruitTotals?toDate=2017-03-13&fromDate=2017-03-11&{%22fruitlist%22:[{%22…,%22Qty%22:%222%22,%22Price%22:%2230%22,%22DateSold%22:%222017-03-12%22}]} Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Sorry, did not notice your were making a GET - it needs to be a POST, and the method marked `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you sir

Comment: It'd be cleaner to put your query string arguments in to your Json too.